# How to hover the name of the next and previous slide on the next and previous button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help to implement a hover function on the arrows of the slider showing the name of the next slide on the "next" arrow and the name of previous slide on the "prev" arrow.

I tried to code it with jQuery but I can't seem to get it working.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: your code will build that where is your code

Comment: Could you post some of the code you are currently using? Without it, we can't do anything.

Comment: Just use the `title` attribute for tooltips?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zYDD9/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it like;

```
$("#next").mouseenter(function () {
    // Next slide name
    $(this).html("N1");
});
$("#next").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).html("Next");
});

$("#prev").mouseenter(function () {
    // Prev slide name
    $(this).html("P1");
});
$("#prev").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).html("Prev");
});
```

jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zYDD9/3/)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer.
I made a similar function with an hover but the name must change (I have 5 slides). Do you have an idea how to implement it with the name changing according to the next or prev slide?
Thanks again